# How do I initiate a dynamic user prompt depending on an API response in Bot Composer?

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I have an API response in which a field gives me an array of objects. I want to prompt the user to select which one of these objects in the array they want to see the details of. For example, if the API response has a field like:

```
"field":[
       {"number":"101","name":"abc","value":"final output 1"},
       {"number":"102","name":"xyz","value":"final output 2"}
      ]
```

I want the prompt/card to ask which number and name the user wants to choose, accordingly I want to show the corresponding value to the user. The number of objects in the array can vary. I would prefer if this prompt is in the form of an adaptive card like the one in the attached image, but any solution would do using bot composer's capabilities.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One viable solution would be to [build a card in code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/authoring-cards/net). You can parse the response from the API and use it to create a card which can then be sent by the bot. Since this is Composer, you can look into creating a [custom action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-create-custom-actions) to hold this logic.

Comment: Is this still the only option? or they have any other updates? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

As the user AP01 has said, one good solution to this problem is to do it inside the code. You can create a custom component that will execute C#(or nodejs if you use that) code in which you can then easily deserialize/parse/process that json array and create a custom card that will then be display to the user. That is how I did it.